# How to run a Python script upon button click using mod_python without changing browser window

Tags: javascript, python, mod-python, publisher

I am using `mod_python` publisher which is set up and working fine. It allows me to run a Python file in my browser and this Python file has HTML embedded in it. I have defined a click-able image by `input type = "image" onclick = "some action"`. When I click the image it takes me to a JavaScript function which then performs `window.location = "./move"` which then takes me to a Python function. The problem is that the browser window redirects to that function, i. e. `localhost/scripts` becomes `localhost/scripts/move`. Is it possible to execute the script without having the browser window change? I can post code if needs be.

Comment: Is that your own javascript function which resets window.location? What does the move function do?

Comment: yes it basically justs redirects to the python function. Move allows for a servo motor to move. So i have an arrow button that when i click it causes a servo motor to turn

Comment: Can't you redirect back to /scripts at the end of move?

Comment: Yes i can but i have video feed that keeps refreshing when i do that. So basically the whole page refreshes again and the video feed stops and starts

Comment: Why are you setting window.location? Can't you just call move()?

Comment: i have tried that but it does not seem to work

Comment: You probably want to use some AJAX.

Comment: "i have tried that but it does not seem to work" is not helpful. You can use the javascript debugger to see what happens.

Comment: I am sorry about that. Maybe if I post some code would that help?

Comment: I have the same need: how to launch python code on the server from javascript without calling a script that will reload page ? (some post without any return value/feedback)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, I've just found using Ajax/XmlHttpRequest is simple and work well for that, even if your server is a python SimpleServer style.

You just link this Javascript code from your button:

```
// send a request, but don't refresh page
xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("GET", "?like", true);
xhttp.send();
```